tsc compiled js file failed run in Chrome extension: Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token 'export'
I am creating a Chrome extension using typescript.
I use tsc CLI to transpile TS files to JS files.
The extension failed to load with error message:

Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token 'export'

My tsconfig.json file is as follows:
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "es5",
    "module": "ESNext",
    "outDir": "dist",
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true,
    "strict": true,
    "skipLibCheck": true
  }
}

Note: I have tried different module options: commonjs, ES6. None of them works.
What's the correct configuration to transpile ts to be used?

https://github.com/chibat/chrome-extension-typescript-starter/blob/main/tsconfig.json

Hi @JaredSmith. I tried your config, it still doesn't work. I have searched more, Do I have to use a bundler like vite to bundle the js file?

Using CommonJS, tsc will emit require which is not available in a browser environment. Using ESNext, it will emit export which cannot be run as a non-module script (you'll get SyntaxError if you try). So you need something that converts it to another format. A bundler like rollup can do it. Webpack is another option

It's not my config, and no you shouldn't necessarily.
